# Moved NAS, need to repoint iTunes

Tags: itunes, network, music, nas

I had a fully working iTunes library, the .itl on my MBP, and music in my organised folders on my NAS share. This setup I would like to keep as iTunes manages my iPod but nothing else.  So I don't need to have my music local, and I don't need the entire itunes stuff (itl, xml etc) on the nas.

I've bought a new NAS and moved the files across, unfortunately the path is different. It was \NAS\media\music and now its \NAS\music.

I thought I could resolve this by altering the XML, deleting the .itl and importing the XML, but a) this is seems slower than it should be, and b) failed to import everything, one playlist was half empty.

Is there another way? Or something else?

I'm using Synology DS414play, and its currently SMB shared and not AFP or NFS.

Latest OSX (10.10.3) and iTunes (12.1.2.27)

Comment: Tweak the xml, break the itl rather than delete it - looking for my answer...

Comment: iTunes supports having the library organization files in one directory and the media files in another. What is your end goal for these two directories. Do you want everything in one iTunes folder or do you want that still on your user home folder and the media elsewhere. Also, edit the post to have  your OS and iTunes versions specified. See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201979 for how to let the program move the media. I'll put a temp hold on this while we work out if it's dupe or a new question.

Comment: see a combo of http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/163601/85275 and http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/157670/85275 That way you should only lose a couple of album covers, everything else should stay intact - & it's factors faster

Comment: I'd restore your old library-files from timemachine to the state before fiddling with it. Then when you open iTunes and try to play a track it can't find I think it prompts you to choose the new location of the track and tell it to apply that to all others.

Comment: @Tetsujin your first link was perfect!  It still took pretty much all day, I've got 34k tracks, so I don't know if that seems reasonable, there was very sporadic network activity as it did the work.  Now its doing the artwork and its a lot more consistent network access.

Comment: Last time I did it it really only took about 15/20 mins, though I've only 6k tracks, it did low at about 5k tough, so maybe that's progressive