# Moving/Editing iTunes XML file path, off of mapped network drive

Tags: itunes, network, nas

I have a similar problem to this post, but slightly different so I'm asking separately.  [iTunes: Move files off a network drive](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/157665/itunes-move-files-off-a-network-drive)

I'm transitioning from Windows to Mac.

Current iTunes music files are stored on a NAS drive. I mapped the network drive to drive letter A:/

I've exported the iTunes library as an XML file. However, when I look inside of the XML, it lists the file location as

```
<key>Major Version</key><integer>1</integer>

<key>Minor Version</key><integer>1</integer>

<key>Date</key><date>2019-11-21T06:38:06Z</date>

<key>Application Version</key><string>12.10.0.7</string>

<key>Features</key><integer>5</integer>

<key>Show Content Ratings</key><true/>

<key>Music Folder</key><string>file://localhost/A:/</string>

<key>Library Persistent ID</key><string>DCA8633F96A3132D</string>

<key>Tracks</key>

<dict>

    <key>11111</key>

    <dict>

        <key>Track ID</key><integer>11111</integer>

        <key>Name</key><string>Track</string>

        <key>Artist</key><string>Artist</string>

        <key>Album Artist</key><string>Album</string>

        <key>Composer</key><string>Composer</string>

        <key>Album</key><string>Test (Bonus Track Version)</string>

        <key>Genre</key><string>Hip-Hop/Rap</string>

        <key>Kind</key><string>Purchased AAC audio file</string>

        <key>Size</key><integer>8920821</integer>

        <key>Total Time</key><integer>239543</integer>

        <key>Disc Number</key><integer>1</integer>

        <key>Disc Count</key><integer>1</integer>

        <key>Track Number</key><integer>3</integer>

        <key>Track Count</key><integer>18</integer>

        <key>Year</key><integer>2009</integer>

        <key>Date Modified</key><date>2015-08-09T04:45:47Z</date>

        <key>Date Added</key><date>2016-04-13T00:51:29Z</date>

        <key>Bit Rate</key><integer>256</integer>

        <key>Sample Rate</key><integer>44100</integer>

        <key>Normalization</key><integer>2045</integer>

        <key>Artwork Count</key><integer>1</integer>

        <key>Sort Album</key><string>Test (Bonus Track Version)</string>

        <key>Sort Artist</key><string>Artist</string>

        <key>Sort Name</key><string>Name</string>

        <key>Persistent ID</key><string>12739182731</string>

        <key>Explicit</key><true/>

        <key>Track Type</key><string>File</string>

        <key>Purchased</key><true/>

        <key>Location</key><string>file://localhost/A:/Music/Artist/Track.m4a</string>

        <key>File Folder Count</key><integer>-1</integer>

        <key>Library Folder Count</key><integer>-1</integer>

    </dict>
```

Without relocating the actual music files, how do I edit this mapped drive (A:/) because Mac is not finding it.

The issue I'm having is when I use a third party app to read iTunes playlists, it can't locate any of the files on the Mac. I get why, because it's looking in the NAS storage drive.

Comment: I think the trouble with recent iTunes versions is that it no longer will build from the XML file, nor does just breaking the ITL file cause it to re-analyse the paths. It's been a very long time since I had to do this, so I await answers eagerly.

Comment: I wonder if this might still be useful - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/230207/how-to-share-an-itunes-library-between-mac-windows/230208#230208